# Binomial expansion with gamma function

Tags: riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

I'm studying Euler proof of $\zeta(2)$. There are several proof but I'm on one. I found in a book this expression for binomial but I can't find where it comes from

$(1+y)^{-t} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(t)} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \frac{\Gamma(t+n)}{n!} y^n$.

Does some know where it comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This binomial theorem is the Maclaurin series of $(1+y)^{-t}$. You may prove by induction that the $n$th derivative of this function is $(-1)^n\frac{\Gamma(t+n)}{\Gamma(t)}(1+y)^{-t-n}$, which gives the desired coefficients when we expand around $y=0$. The remainder term's modulus has an upper bound proportional to $y^{n+1}$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) for details), so the series is valid if $|y|<1$.

Comment: Dear @J.G. any reference for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ \Gamma(n+s)}{n!}t^n = \frac{\Gamma(s)}{(1-t)^s}$? Thank you in advance

Comment: @Z.Alfata Expand the RHS by Taylor's theorem, then use $\Gamma(n+s)=\Gamma(s)\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(s+k)$.